# why ng-bind-html is not working in ng-repeat while include ngSanitize in module

Tags: html, angularjs

I am new to the angular js i want to bind the tags inside the ng-repeat i placed ng-bind-html and ng-bind-html-unsafe but not working the output is not comming

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>      

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
 <script>
   var myApp=angular.module('myApp',['ngSanitize'])
   myApp.controller('myController',['$scope',function($scope){
       $scope.items=[{ht:"hi <br> joi",ft:"ji"}];
   }]);
    </script>


<body>
    <div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myController'>
       <div ng-repeat="r in items ">
           <p ng-bind-html-unsafe="{{r.ht}}"></p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

need to use `$sce` to bind the data to `ng-bind-html`

```js
var myApp=angular.module('myApp',['ngSanitize'])
   myApp.controller('myController',['$scope','$sce',function($scope,$sce){
       $scope.items=[{ht:"hi <h1> joi </h1>",ft:"ji"}];      
   }]);
   myApp.filter('unsafe', function($sce) { return $sce.trustAsHtml; });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>      

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
 
 <div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myController'>
    <div ng-repeat="r in items ">
        <p ng-bind-html="r.ht | unsafe"></p> 
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: if we use the heading tag

Comment: did't understand what you are saying

Comment: @Sajeetharan didn't thought about a  filter. nice :D

Comment: <h1>this is name</h1> if i placed this like

Comment: @banu prakash do u want to add ng-bind-html inside <h1> tag

Comment: if i replace of this "hi <br> joi" to hi <h1> joi </h1>

Comment: @banu prakash check the demo again

Comment: thank you for the answer i have one more if i dont place the function is there any alternative direct placing of the ng-bind-html

Comment: @banu prakash you can create a custom filter like the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You are missing > tag in the ng-sanitize script,

change

From

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-sanitize.js">/script>
```

To

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

If you are using ng-sanitize no need to apply the $sce filter to make the safe url,

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp=angular.module('myApp',['ngSanitize'])
  myApp.controller('myController',['$scope','$sce',function($scope,$sce){
   $scope.items=[{ht:"hi <h1> joi </h1>",ft:"ji"}];      
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>      

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
 
 <div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myController'>
    <div ng-repeat="r in items ">
        <h1 ng-bind-html="r.ht"></h1> 
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: @banuprakash you dont need a $sce filter when injecting sanitize

Comment: why i dont get the output why

Comment: where you dint get output?

Comment: what do you mean by removed it

Comment: copy my question code and remove unsafe and check it

Comment: that's because you are missing ng-sanitize

Comment: where i missed it

Comment: You didn't get because you made a mistake. You marked above post as answer which means that helped you why do you bother here